# Encode mjpeg files from within an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'm trying to encode a video file with the `mjpeg` codec on *iOS*. Basically, I'm trying to replicate what this command does

```
ffmpeg -i recording.mp4 -vsync vfr -q:v 9 recording.mjpeg
```

from within an app.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm looking at using the low level *ffmpeg* API to do this like in [this example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html), but I was wondering if somebody knows of a simpler way.

I have also access to the individual video frames in `CMSampleBufferRef` format, in case that makes it easier. `AVAssetWriter` doesn't seem to support `mjpeg`, which is unfortunate, as that would make things super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the code shown in the [transcoding.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c) example, but replacing the encoding codec by `AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG`.